# Can we please stop polling in meta?

Tags: discussion, meta

This is a trend I've noticed that's been going on for quite a while. Whenever someone asks a question on meta, it seems appropriate to answer with two possibilities (or more) and have the community vote on those. **It's not**.

Ask your question, and let people come up with their ideas. Don't create a poll, because that implies there are only two options.

If you don't get answers on your post, that's a different matter. But please, don't self-answer with N possibilities just to get votes on them. Meta is about discussion, and people have opinions different than yours, not everything is yes/no or a/b/c.

Comment: One thing I liked about the polling is that the first answer isn't necessarily the most upvoted one, which seems (at least to me) to happen frequently enough as people are slow/uninterested to recheck meta questions for new answers

Comment: I do agree that they're not great for discussion though.

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko I have seen cases where this claim was overthrown, here on our meta. While it's true that the first answers often get more attention, we take that into account when reviewing consensuses and opinions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I agree. Allow me to quote from [Robert Cartaino♦](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/welcome-stack-overflow-valued-associate-00005/)'s [comment on Meta LifeHacks.SE](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1343/how-medical-is-too-medical/1350#comment1969_1343):

> "[...] If you have thoughts on the issue yourself, please feel free to post it as an answer, but it is generally better to let everyone have a voice by soliciting thoughts and opinions rather pre-posting all sides of the conversation yourself in this type of pseudo-poll. It's not difficult to infer what the community wants from the conversation while allowing for the possibility that there's an issue we have not considered. [**Polling is generally not a good substitute for discussion**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Polling_is_not_a_substitute_for_discussion). Thanks."

Comment: "It's not difficult to infer what the community wants from the conversation" - I dunno, maybe on stacks with a large userbase, we've gone round in circles about many topics very often.

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko You're welcome to collect cases where topics were difficult to be discussed because of a silent majority to show a need for poll-like discussions to have a strong standing by posting them as a separate answer, that's what this thread is here for. :)

Comment: Nah, I think it's more that our decisions aren't very visible, rather than poll questions resolving it